# PHP how to count xml elements in object returned by simplexml_load_file(),

Tags: php

I have inherited some PHP code (but I've little PHP experience) and can't find how to count some elements in the object returned by `simplexml_load_file()`

The code is something like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
for ($x=0; $x<6; $x++) {
   $title = $xml->channel[0]->item[$x]->title[0];
   echo "<li>" . $title . "</li>\n";
}
```

It assumes there will be at least 6 `<item>` elements but sometimes there are fewer so I get warning messages in the output on my development system (though not on live).

How do I extract a count of `<item>` elements in `$xml->channel[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several options, from my most to least favourite (of the ones provided).

- One option is to make use of the [`SimpleXMLIterator`](http://php.net/simplexmliterator) in conjunction with [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/limititerator).

  ```
  $xml   = simplexml_load_file($feed, 'SimpleXMLIterator');
  $items = new LimitIterator($xml->channel->item, 0, 6);
  foreach ($items as $item) {
      echo "<li>{$item->title}</li>\n";
  }
  ```
- If that looks too scary, or not scary enough, then another is to throw XPath into the mix.

  ```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
  $items = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item[position() <= 6]');
  foreach ($items as $item) {
      echo "<li>{$item->title}</li>\n";
  }
  ```
- Finally, with little change to your existing code, there is also.

  ```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
  for ($x=0; $x<6; $x++) {
      // Break out of loop if no more items
      if (!isset($xml->channel[0]->item[$x])) {
          break;
      }
      $title = $xml->channel[0]->item[$x]->title[0];
      echo "<li>" . $title . "</li>\n";
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [`SimpleXMLElement::count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php) as:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$num = $xml->channel[0]->count();
for ($x=0; $x<$num; $x++) {
   $title = $xml->channel[0]->item[$x]->title[0];
   echo "<li>" . $title . "</li>\n";
}
```

Also note that the return of `$xml->channel[0]` is a `SimpleXMLElement` object. This class implements the [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface so we can use it directly in a `foreach` loop:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach($xml->channel[0] as $item {
   $title = $item->title[0];
   echo "<li>" . $title . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get count by count($xml).
I always do it like this:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
 foreach($xml as $key => $one_row) {
        echo $one_row->some_xml_chield;
  }
```

Comment: OK, but 6 is an upper limit for display, I guess I can use `if $count++ >= 6 { break; }` inside the loop.

Comment: Hey, I just find function **simpleXMLToArray**
there [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). 
You can pass xml object to this function and get array, and than you can pass throw element by for($i=0;$i>...){ ... }