# Grab only the latest 3 posts from RSS feed

Tags: php, html, xml, rss

My code below is getting the entire RSS feed, how can I limit this to just retrieve the latest 3 posts? Either that or simply display just the latest 3 and not all posts.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://tutorial.world.edu/feed/");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = (string) $item->title; // Title Post
    $link   = (string) $item->link; // Url Link
    $pubDate   = (string) $item->pubDate; // date
    $description = (string) $item->description; //Description Post
echo '<div class="display-rss-feed"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="" >'.$title.' </a><br/><br/>';
echo $description.'<hr><p style="background-color:#e4f;">'.$pubDate.'</p></div>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that is to count. Starting with zero and counting per each iteration, you just exit the loop if the counter reaches four.

Another possibility is to use the [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) on an `IteratorIterator` on the `Traversable` you've got in question (`$xml->channel->item`).

This is outlined here:

- [How to Paginate lines in a foreach loop with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1679559/367456)

And further related to your question are:

- [PHP how to count xml elements in object returned by simplexml_load_file(),](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505805/367456)
- [PHP - display 'X' items from foreach loop with link to display next 'X' items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258835/367456)
- [XML Feeds & PHP - Limit the number of items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7876931/367456)
- [XML pagination with PHP [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15708638/367456)

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_slice($xml->channel->item, 0, 3) in for sothat it grap only up to 3 first posts

Comment: does not work is not an array.